# Duplicating elements of a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following tuplelist and dictionary in Python 2.7

```
lambdatuple = [(8.0,), (4.0,), (5.0,), (8.0, 4.0), (8.0, 5.0), (4.0, 5.0), (8.0, 4.0, 5.0)]
muscenarios = {0: 240.0, 1: 600.0, 2: 480.0, 3: 300.0, 4: 297.1, 5: 526.8, 6: 337.1}
```

Based on the tuple length of each element in lambdatuple, I want to duplicate my element in the muscenarios such that it will become:

```
muscenarios = {0: 240.0, 1: 600.0, 2: 480.0, 3: 300.0, 4: 300.0, 5: 297.1, 6: 297.1,
               7: 526.8, 8: 526.8, 9:337.1, 10: 337.1, 11: 337.1}
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this yourself? If so, please show your attempt and describe what it is doing wrong. Also, please expand on your problem description. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, good question. Of course, I made. It was late night when I posted it. With a clear mind, I got my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind. I found my solution. The following code did what I tried to do:

```
muscenariosnew = []
for j in range(len(lambdatuple)):
    muscenariosnew.append([muscenarios.values()[j]] * len(lambdatuple[j]))
muscenariosnew = [item for sublist in muscenariosnew for item in sublist]
muscenarios
[240.0,
 600.0,
 480.0,
 300.0,
 300.0,
 297.1,
 297.1,
 526.8,
 526.8,
 337.1,
 337.1,
 337.1]
```